# Adding fonts in Tailwind CSS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, fonts, tailwind-css

I'm pretty new to Laravel and Tailwind, but I'm trying to learn as I go with different projects. Currently, I'm working on importing a font. I have downloaded the font from google fonts which gave me a TTF file. I put it in /resources/fonts/NewTegomin-Regular.ttf. Now I can't figure out how to use this font.

**app.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base{
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'New Tegomin';
        src: url(../fonts/NewTegomin-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
    }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'chalk': ['New Tegomin', 'serif']
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="logo flex items-center font-chalk text-3xl">Title</div>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to import the fonts on your `app.css or main css file`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Tegomin&display=swap');

@layer base {
    body {
        font-family: 'New Tegomin', sans-serif;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to identify the font neither sans-serif or serif ?